# static function not working on serial port

Tags: c#

I'm trying to control board in two different ways. One is with direct control from computer itself and the other is with network control.Following is relavent part of what I've coded.

As you can see, key part of both `DirectControl` and `RemoteControl` is identical. But the latter part that deals with serialport doesn't work on `RemoteControl` while the former part, sound playing works well for both of them. And there's no error message at all.

Is there any problem I'm not noticing? Any advice would be thanked in advance.

```
_httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:5000/");
_httpListener.Start();
Thread _responseThread = new Thread(ResponseThread);
_responseThread.Start();

public static SerialPort my_serial = new SerialPort();
static string target_channel = "002";

my_serial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serial_DataReceived);
byte[] serial_send_data = new byte[8];

my_serial.BaudRate = 9600;
my_serial.PortName = port_check.ToString();
if (!my_serial.IsOpen)
{
  try
  {
    my_serial.Open();
    my_serial.Write("$RLB" + Bchannel + "\r");
  }
  catch
  { }
}

private DirectControl(){
  sound.Play();
  my_serial.Write('$'+ target_channel+ "RL10F\r");
}

static void RemoteControl()
{
  sound.Play();
  my_serial.Write('$'+ target_channel+ "RL10F\r");
}

static void ResponseThread()
{
  while (true)
  {
    HttpListenerContext context = _httpListener.GetContext();
    if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
    {
      RemoteControl();
    }
    byte[] _responseArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<html><head><title>Localhost server -- port 5000</title></head>" +
    "<body><form method='POST'><button>OPEN</button></form></body></html>");
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(_responseArray, 0, _responseArray.Length);
    context.Response.KeepAlive = false;
    context.Response.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: How is it supposed to work? I don't see any code telling the `SerialPort` which port to send data to. Are you doing that somewhere else?

Comment: I'm trying to control the electric lock with `SerialPort` by sending a specific signal through the `SerialPort` and serial port setting part is done in the other part of code. I guess problem doesn't lie in that part because the `DirectControl` function works and unlocks the electric lock but `RemoteControl` function doesn't work at all

Comment: So, you have your own `SerialPort` class, or is `my_serial` the normal `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`? Also, where are you opening your port?

Comment: `my_serial` is normal `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`, and opening code was just added.

Comment: The problem is solved after I rebooted computer because of other stuff, but I still just don't get how I did it. Maybe it was something to do with the computer itself I guess...

Comment: If every you find yourself writing `try { ... } catch { }` you should have a bit of a think as to why you're hiding errors.